# react bootstrap Model box doesn't work in react 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am facing a issue during implemantions of modal pop up box in reactjs 16 version. i am using this [react-bootstrap example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#modals-live).
below is the code, take a look and let me know your thoughts.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class ModelFirst extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };

    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }

  close() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  open() {
    console.log('open');
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Click to get the full Modal experience!</p>
        <Button
          bsStyle="primary"
          bsSize="large"
          onClick={this.open}
        >
          Launch demo modal
        </Button>

        <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <h4>Overflowing text to show scroll behavior</h4>
            <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</p>
            <p>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

below is the error i faced.

[image]

this is the my dependencies i have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.3",
    "react-date-picker": "^6.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-overlays": "^0.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
    "validate.js": "^0.11.1"
  },
```

i have looking for the solutions from last 15 hours, but couldn't found it. i have checked the react-bootstrap package closed issue but couldn't found the solutions.

thanks in advances.

**update:
solution is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46707920/2442747)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Modal component from the react-bootstrap library is currently incompatible with React v16 and there is no officially released implementation that works at the moment. There are some monkey patches that people have shared that bypass the error but at the cost of the UI animation. See the following from [connorjburton](https://github.com/connorjburton%20'connorjburton'):

```
import { Modal as ReactOverlayModal } from 'react-overlays';

class Modal extends ReactOverlayModal {
  focus() {};
}

export default Modal;
```

I have not personally tried this monkey patch.

There are currently several pull requests attempting to fix this issue on the react-overlays repository and the maintainers have [asked](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-overlays/issues/188#issuecomment-333373699) for assistance.

UPDATE

This issue has been resolved in react-overlays v0.7.3. The parent package react-bootstrap will download this updated version as a dependency.

Comment: hey @MatthewTFarley thanks for replying, i tried to implement the above patch but couldn't understand where to put this file. can you guide me to implementing this class.
do i need to put this in index file in root level or in component. thanks in advance.

Comment: @RahulMangal One way to make use of this patch is to put the patched component definition in its own file in the same directory as your other component files, export it, then import the patched version of Modal and use it instead of the one from `react-bootstrap` anywhere you are using the Modal component. Don't forget to remove the Modal import from `react-bootstrap`.

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer which i applied. Put the below patch in index.js file located at project root folder, where you use the provider.

```
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/node_modules/react-overlays/lib/Modal';
Modal.prototype.componentWillMount = function componentWillMount() {
  this.focus = function focus() {};
};
```

below is the dependencies which i use.
new installed libraries

```
1: react-overlays: "^0.8.2",
```

updated existing libraries

```
1: react: "^16.0.0",
2: react-dom: "^16.0.0",
3: react-bootstrap: "^0.31.3",
```

if someone stuck somewhere just let me know, i will help them out.